# Checkboxes for each MS Word paragraph to enable/disable paragraph

Tags: microsoft-word, macros

We have some very long templates that go through several iterations during a design lifecycle.  Many times, the templates have far more information than is needed in most cases, so the unnecessary paragraphs are deleted from the document.  However, it is not uncommon for the design to change later and require a removed paragraph to be added back in which usually involves snagging the information back out of the template and fitting it back in.  Also, more often than not, people use the edited version without realizing that there was something in the template that they should have put back into their document.

The documents are very structured and fall into an outline format.
1. Has anyone seen or created a macro that could be applied to the entire document that would add an invisible checkbox to every single outlined paragraph?
2. When the checkbox is checked, I would like the paragraph and all of its sub-levels to be hidden from printing, but not deleted.
In using this method, I could hide and unhide relevant information without having to manage various document versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the hidden text feature, hidden text won't be printed.
To do this you can use the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+H`on the selected paragraph(s), if you then need to unhide the paragraph you can use the shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+8`, which is the same as `Ctrl+(`, to show the paragraph marks and then proceed to use `Ctrl+Shift+H` again to unhide or, if you need all the hidden text, just access the printing options and check the "Print Hidden Text" checkbox, to do that, follow the steps bellow:

---

[Open the "File" menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odOZq.png)

[Click on the tab "Print"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6CqF.png)

[Click on the "Page Setup" in the bottom of the printing setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7tcm.png)

[Click on the "Paper" tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BS6V.png)

[Click on "Printing Options"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkEps.png)

[Check the "Print Hidden Text"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4KqF.png)

---

You can find more info about hidden text [here](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/ms-office-tips/word-hidden-text/) and about Microsoft Word Shortcuts [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-Microsoft-Word-on-Windows-95ef89dd-7142-4b50-afb2-f762f663ceb2).

Comment: I am aware of the hidden text feature.  I am trying to take this into a form that others can hide and un-hide sections dynamically, hence the checkbox macro.  I didn't know the keyboard shortcut previously, though, so that was helpful

Comment: Maybe you could build it in Excel, you can format it to an A4 paper page, remove the guide lines and add the checkboxes to hide the cells, it's rather easy to hide cells in excel with a macro